# Provisioning: Install a Mac app with iCloud for testing

Tags: xcode, macos, icloud, provisioning-profile, cloudkit

I am working on a Mac app which works with iCloud KVS & CloudKit container of my iOS app which is already in production. All works fine when I run the app from Xcode directly. However, I need to Archive > Export and move it to the `/Applications` folder because that's [how the system picks up Safari Extension Companion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35159706/2979418).

But when I try to run the exported app, it immediately crashes and the following error is printed in Console:

[image: /Users/rinat/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-03-21 at 5.32.58 PM.png]

When exporting the app, I tried to choose between Development-signed Application (as required here in the [CloudKit docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/TestingYourApp/TestingYourApp.html)) and Developer ID (as required in SO answer linked above), also between iCloud Development / Production modes. I tried to recreate Certificates and provisioning profiles, making sure that I have iCloud enabled for my App ID (and iOS container is selected).

When I do export, there are a few folders titled "A" and I don't remember having them before enabling iCloud for my project:

[image]

What am I missing here? Thanks!